# I am an US immigrant before but left the country I would like to withdraw may 401k

Tags: united-states, 401k, non-resident, retirement-plan, withdrawal

*How will I withdraw my 401k?

I don't have any information left, washed out by the storm august 19, 2013*

Answer (score 1):

> How will I withdraw my 401k?

You'll fill a form requesting a withdrawal. You will probably have to pay taxes and if  you're not qualified to withdraw yet - 10% penalty.

> I don't have any information left, washed out by the storm august 19, 2013

You should probably contact the employer (start with the HR/payroll department) and ask them to send you the plan details.

You should consider talking to a tax adviser familiar both with the US tax law and your home country regulations in order to better plan this withdrawal.